# Can Duplicati preserve file dates and times?

Tags: duplicati

This is a continuation of: [Duplicati and Backup of live Pervasive Database Missing Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56379756/duplicati-and-backup-of-live-pervasive-database-missing-data)

We have attempted to restore a database data directory. What we are expecting to see in the backup is an exact mirror of what was backed up the night prior.

We are still not seeing all of the data in the restore directory. As far as we can tell, Duplicati seems to be using either the modified date, and or file size of each file when determining what files to back up. Can someone please confirm this one way or the other?

Is there a way to have Duplicati take a backup of only files whose metadata has changed, instead of using the file date and or file size?

Also, on the completion of every restore, there is a modal box that says "8500 Warnings" but we can't see all of them in the log.

What we can see in the log is:

MetadataWriteFailed
Failed to apply metadata to file

---

**EDIT:**
We uninstalled Duplicati Beta and installed Canary in its place. What we see now, is all of our data. All of the rows are being backed up, whereas in Beta, they are not; we are missing rows of data.

One other thing that we noticed was that when the Beta version restores, all of the date/time values for every file are set to the date and time of the restore. With Canary, all of the date/time values are preserved.

Using Canary, we no longer see the warning "MetadataWriteFailed Failed to apply metadata to file"

Is this intended behavior between both versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this intended behavior between both versions?

The canary build has a lot of fixes. I do not recall what was changed with the metadata restore, but if the metadata restore fails (as you see in the beta) that would leave the files with the restore date.

There should not be any changes as to what files are being backed up, so I am not sure what you mean with "we are missing rows of data".

Comment: Thanks again, Kenneth